# Connect to Redis using BusinessWorks 6

Tags: tibco, businessworks, tibco-business-works

I'm starting to learn BW6 and have a project where I need to populate a data cache. For this cache I want to use Redis. 
Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be an adapter I can use to do this. There are several java clients I could use but since it's all new to me I wanted to avoid doing custom Java right away. Is there another way to read and write from Redis without custom Java in BW6?

Comment: I'm looking at a Redis JDBC client: https://github.com/mtpettyp/jdbc-redis . As a Java library Jedis is my current frontrunner...

Comment: are you able to use the library mentioned in the comment and proceed?

Comment: Jedis works fine. BW6 has excellent Java support. Also added JWT support the way.